# Icinga2: How to do notification in waves?

Tags: monitoring, icinga, icinga2, notification

I am currently setting up my Icinga2 in a new structure and wanted to add a few features. I am done with 90% but I miss exactly one feature: Notify me in a wave.

Let me explain:

Whenever an error happens I am wanting the following scenario:

- instant: send mail
- after 5 minutes: send Chat notification
- 10 Minutes: send SMS
- 30 Minutes: call me
- At minute 40 repeat from send mail

Right now everything happens at the same time so I have NotificationCommands and Notifications, but I don't know how to  setup the top configuration. Is someone able to help me here?

have a nice day,

Bastian

Comment: Look into [notification escalation](https://docs.icinga.com/icinga2/latest/doc/module/icinga2/toc#!/icinga2/latest/doc/module/icinga2/chapter/monitoring-basics#notification-escalations). The idea is that you define several contacts and notification methods and configure the escalation method to use them in the order you desire.

Comment: Perfect, works out of the box... So much options and I just did not see it...

Comment: This works perfect: https://serverfault.com/questions/856716/icinga2-how-to-do-notification-in-waves?noredirect=1#comment1101112_856716 Thanks Sven for your help!